# Have 4g home network and want to expand ethernet ports wirelessly... how?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, switch

So for my home network I have a superb 4g unlimited data SIM plan that sits in a TP-Link 4g router with 4 * ethernet ports. I also have a Netgear 8-port ethernet switch connected to one of the ports on my router. All works well.

However, in a separate area of my home, I have several devices that I want to be able to connect to the home network via ethernet cable, not wirelessly.

I am not a network expert, and am wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this please? I do have a few spare routers (one of which is an Apple AirPort Extreme) if this could be utilised, or would I need to find some form of a wireless ethernet switch to connect first to the wireless network, then use the ethernet ports in it to connect to the devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an AP Client. Many routers have this mode built in - generally you would disable DHCP and ignire the WAN port and have the WIFI interface.set to AP client mode.

If your router does not have this mode but can run dd-wrt, flashing dd-wt onto it will give you this functionality.

Comment: Ok, thanks David, so if I understand correctly - I can use an existing spare router (configured somehow in AP mode - which I need to work out how to do) to pick up the 4g home wifi network from my main TP-Link router, and this router will then subsequently distribute and switch the inputed wifi signal to its available ethernet ports? yes?

Comment: @John: Your main router is an "AP" (an access point); your second device needs to be an AP _client_ – more commonly called a "station" (or "STA (client)" or "station bridge" or maybe "WDS client", there's no consistency)